# Linux `system()` doesn't find program even though it is in the same folder

Tags: linux

I have a program which calls another program by executing `system(..)`. This other program is located in the same folder as the main program but for whatever reason, `system(..)` returns with `sh: 1: program_name: not found`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the current workin directory is not in PATH.  Use `./program_name` instead.

Comment: Of course, you are rather presuming that the "same folder" here is _also_ the working directory, which it may not be.

Comment: That indeed I am.